# Spyder - IPython console - enable printing across the screen width

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I am using the IPython console through Spyder. Is it possible to allow the console to print across the entire screen? The included picture shows the amount of empty space in the console. It's especially frustrating when I print a dataframe with many columns and I'm limited to seeing 6 at a time.

[image: Spyder console pic]

Comment: Add the code you are using to print what you get right now

Comment: @BenMohorc unless you know something I do not, the code is irrelevant. It's a text-wrapping feature built in.

Comment: @roganjosh You are probably right. I saw a question about output errors with no code behind it. Didn't occur to me it might just be a console setting/feature.

Answer (score 3):

for pandas.DataFrame objects you can set the display width as explained in docs

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html

to whatever limit you wish. They say IPython does not run in a terminal (when used within Spyder), so it cannot auto-detect the width, hence you should provide a specific value as in, ex:

```
pandas.set_option('display.width', 140)
```

and it will display up to 140 cols, then truncate.